# Install bootloader for Windows 10 after Ubuntu installation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-10, grub, bootloader

I installed Ubuntu on an external drive following a tutorial and the tutorial said that I had to install the bootloader into the external drive. After the installation finished I could boot to Ubuntu when I had the external drive connected. Whenever I don't have the disk connected I get a grub menu where it tells me to write a command. How can I get the Windows bootloader back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it isn't hard to get the windwos bootloader back. Have you tried [that](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/33433/restore-the-windows-boot-loader-after-an-ubuntu-update/)?

1. **Get a windows CD/ DVD and boot it on your Computer using the BIOS-Bootmanager**
2. **Go to option "Repair the Computer" and restore the Computer using System Restore**
3. **Alternatively you could use "Startup Repair"**

[image]

4. **The best way is the manual way. Use the Command Prompt and type:**

> bootrec /rebuildbcd

**and enter "Y" to add it**

5. **Restart to finish!**

Comment: I downloaded the windows 10 iso from microsofts site and put it in a bootable USB. My intention was to use some repair function but when I had this USB in I actually got to my windows 10 installation, the thing is that if I restart and take the usb out I get the same problem. So how can I fix the boot record from inside windows?

Comment: Here the whole procedure is explained. http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/33433/restore-the-windows-boot-loader-after-an-ubuntu-update/